# Public key issue with command line in sourceTree (git )

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I usually use git on linux and I'm not familiar with sourceTree on windows ( c# project ), the interface is usefull to follow the tree, but I would like to the use commande line .

I really don't understand, I generated my ssh key with sourceTree agent and load with "Pageant", I added the public key on my bitbucket account.

And it works. I can clone/pull/push from the sourceTree interface

[image: fetch with sourceTree's interface]

But using the sourceTree command line mode doesn't work

[image: command line doesn't works]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to generate public key from console.

like this

```
 ssh-keygen
```

it will generate public key that you can add it in Bitbucket

for more info visit this [Tutorial](http://www.zainabed.com/2014/10/ssh-public-key-for-github-and-bitbucket.html)

Answer (score 4):

1. Set *SSH Key* to a PuTTY private key (.ppk) and set *SSH Client* to `PuTTY / Plink`
2. Set an environment variable `GIT_SSH` to the path of *plink.exe*, for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\tools\putty\plink.exe`

---

Of course you could have a separate, global OpenSSH key in `%HOMEPATH%\.ssh\id_rsa` but then you would lose the advantage of SourceTree loading the correct key automatically.

By the way, I can confirm that neither of these work:

- Setting *SSH Key* to an OpenSSH private key and using `OpenSSH` as *SSH Client*
- Setting *SSH Key* to a PuTTY private key and using `PuTTY / Plink` as *SSH Client*

Comment: This worked for me.  Specifically, it was the missing GIT_SSH environment variable that caused the problems.  Once that was added with the path to my own separate installation of PuTTY's PLINK.EXE, all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of the above was necessary to make it work for me. The only necessary aspect to consider is that by default git (and maybe other apps) expect your ssh key in `c:/users/<user>/.ssh`. Mind the dot! After I renamed my ssh folder to .ssh all started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-3.4.8\tools\putty\plink.exe" bitbucket.org

change username and app-